# Run a schedule function for every user in node js

Tags: node.js, schedule

I need to find the best possible way to do the following task.
I have different users let's say (over 500) and all users have a scheduled function that need to be run twice every day. But if any of the user's phone is off. Then of course that function wont work since its code is written on client side.
now what i want to do is Run a scheduled function in the backend using **Node js**, but idk how to run that for every user. **(note : every user has different schedules)**. Thats why i wrote that in client side, but with with a possibility of phone might be switched off so its bit off to do that.
What should i do in this scenario? any leads?

Comment: Depending upon how frequently and accurately the task needs to run for each user, you can either set a timer on the server for each user so each user's task runs at its appointed time or you can set one recurring timer on the server and then query which user's have a task to run.  In case you're wondering, nodejs is very efficient with lots of timers so you can pretty much have as many as you want.

Comment: Can you post your existing scheduling code here? See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You might want to take a look at [node-cron](https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron) for cron (scheduled) jobs.